# Python/Selenium: How can I emulate extensions such as uBlock or AdBlock using a headless Chrome driver?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I'm using Selenium/ChromeDriver in Python. Using the ChromeDriver options in my code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('load-extension=' +uBlockExtensionPATH)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

However, **headless Chrome does not support the use of extensions** as per this [answer](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/headless-dev/nEoeUkoNI0o/hSlY4fQzBgAJ). I was able to get headless Chrome working with my current Python script, and everything works fine, but it takes a long time to reach sites due to third-party advertisements/analytics/requests.

Before I implemented the headless ChromeDriver, I used the standard **non-headless** ChromeDriver and imported the uBlock extension to eliminate third-party sites from slowing down my tests.

For example, completing my tests **without** the -headless option and **with** uBlock extension would take roughly 20 seconds or so. However, completing my tests **with** the -headless option and **without** uBlock, my tests take about a minute to complete. This defeats the purpose of my original goal of cutting down testing time, which was why I wanted to use the headless Chrome Driver in the first place.

Since I can't import Chrome extensions in headless mode, how can I block third-party ads/analytics/requests (**a.k.a. the purpose of uBlock**)?

I'm not too knowledgeable in proxies or anything network related. I know an option would be to **blacklist** any hosts that are causing the slow connection, but these hosts are constantly changing and would be too much to blacklist each individually.

Comment: To further clarify: You know those little messages in the bottom left corner of Chrome when you're loading a site? Those are basically what's slowing me down. For example I'd see: "Performing TLS handshake with: " or "Waiting for amazon.ds.analytics.com" and etc. These get eliminated with uBlock, but obviously extensions are not possible with headless Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

As extensions are not supported in headless mode, Proxy servers seem to be the best possible course of action here.

You can try using https://github.com/epitron/mitm-adblock to setup a local proxy server (written in python and easy to set up) and add `--proxy-server=localhost:8118` when starting up chrome. It supports AdblockPlus easylist which should be fairly comprehensive.

You can also try https://github.com/Artificial-University/adblock-proxy which is written in node but seems more full-fledged and recently updated.